# How to add class for all parents of one siblings element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, addclass

I have this markup:

```
<li class="parent">
   <span class="button"></span>
   <li class="parent">
      <span class="button"></span>
      <li class="parent">
         <span class="button"></span>
      </li>
   <li>
<li>
```

Now I need to give a class for each parent, depending on the button clicked.

So i do this:

```
var main_ctnr = $('.main_cntnr'),
    main_prnt = main_ctnr.find('li.parent');

$('span.button').on('click', function(){
   main_prnt.prevAll().addClass('some_class);
}
```

And solve the need to have:

after click on first button

```
<li class="parent some_class">
   <span class="button"></span>
   <li class="parent">
      <span class="button"></span>
      <li class="parent">
         <span class="button"></span>
      </li>
   <li>
<li>
```

after click on second button

```
<li class="parent some_class">
   <span class="button"></span>
   <li class="parent some_class">
      <span class="button"></span>
      <li class="parent">
         <span class="button"></span>
      </li>
   <li>
<li>
```

and third

```
<li class="parent some_class">
   <span class="button"></span>
   <li class="parent some_class">
      <span class="button"></span>
      <li class="parent some_class">
         <span class="button"></span>
      </li>
   <li>
<li>
```

It must act only within the first parent, so that the earlier part of the main parent did not receive the class already. No this situation may be, after click `this_button`:

```
<li class="parent some_class">
   <span class="button"></span>
   <li class="parent">
      <span class="button"></span>
      <li class="parent">
         <span class="button"></span>
      </li>
   <li>
<li>    
<li class="parent some_class">
   <span class="this_button"></span>
   <li class="parent">
      <span class="button"></span>
      <li class="parent">
         <span class="button"></span>
      </li>
   <li>
<li>
```

This is harsh so from the mountains - Much thx for help.

Comment: In the `click` handler of the buttons, just use `$(this).parents(".parent").addClass("some_class");`

Comment: but after this i will have class for all of li parents, i need to add it only for main parent element

Comment: Dude, do you mean to say that you want to apply class only for the first parent, on click of any button, If 'yes', then this should be your solution
$('span.button').on('click', function(){
    $('li.parent:first').addClass('some_class');
});

Comment: @SAM: Your selector is agnostic of scope. that will match the first `.parent` on the page, regardless of which `.button` was clicked.

Comment: not for first, for all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `.parent()` (direct parent) or `.parents()` (traverse up through all parents) not `.prevAll`. `.next*` and `.prev*` are for *siblings*.

From there you can adjust your selector to filter/narrow your search, or change how many parents you want to traverse, e.g. `$(this).parents('.parent')` matches all parent nodes with the class `parent` applied.

To visualize it, if you had:

```
$('span').click(function(){
  $(this)./*one of the below methods*/;
});
```

See how each method would react if called off of `$(this)`:

```
                            .parent() .parents() .parents('foo') .parents('bar')
<div>                                  x
  <div class="foo">                    x          x
    <div class="foo bar">    x         x          x               x
      <span>target</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*An `x` means it would be returned in the result.*